# Enabling a feature only for a specific market

Tags: android

I want to disable a particular feature of my app in the US market but keep it enabled for other markets.

I would like to know if there is way to determine in which market was the app initially installed.

Comment: You can try to look into some broadcasts `GoogleAnalytics` sends when your app is installed, and decide at runtime? Another solution maybe to use the user's Locale and determine based on that...

Comment: Alternative (easier) idea: check the current locale and disable the feature if it is **en-rUS** (or is it **en_US**)? OK, disable it if it ends in **US**... ;) or it has an **en*US** pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Get the user location with the `LocationService` and make a decision based on that.

It's not really telling "in which market the app was initially installed" but it should be close enough.